# Where can I find apoc.conf for Neo4j Desktop?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Need to set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in **apoc.conf**, but cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Neo4j does not require a separate apoc.conf file. You can simply add the setting to the neo4j.conf file, restart, and it should work.

As of 12/5/2022: this works for both the `apoc.import.file.enabled =true` AND the `apoc.export.file.enabled =true` settings.

Comment: I am not able to locate this file, is it the same as neo4j.conf ?

Comment: yes, add it to neo4j.conf. 
Also if you get error using apoc, see this https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-procedure-is-not-available-due-to-having-restricted-access-rights-check-configuration/

Comment: Find the location of "neo4j.conf" and create that apoc.conf file beside that.

Comment: In version 5.4 I had to create a separate file`apoc.conf` as Cihan Yakar wrote. By adding apoc configs to `neo4j.conf`, DBMS was not starting.

Answer (score 1):

As some commenters wrote under another answer, as of my writing I needed to create `apoc.conf` in the same directory of `neo4j.conf` with `apoc.export.file.enabled=true` inside it and restart neo4j.